# create a drop down list in search bar in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have created a dropdown list on my webpage using a basic  statement in HTML but it is in the body section of my page. I added a search bar in my topnav and have been attempting to move this dropdown list so it appears there once someone clicks in the field or starts to type, but the data in the dropdown list is from an SQL database (corporate company) and not a predefined list such as . I am using local ASP to pull the data from SQL, and HTML & Java to populate it.

Does anyone know how to write the HTML & Java so that the dropdown list with my data appears in the search bar once someone clicks in the search bar? My code is below.

> This is my logic that originally worked

```
<select id="containerlist" onchange="newcontainer()"></select>
```

> This is the logic that I have been trying

```
<div class="search-container">
 <input id='input' type="text" placeholder="Container #.." onkeyup="filterFunction()"<select id="containerlist" onchange="newcontainer()"</select>/>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

> I also tried the code below but not sure what I would put in the value section for the option...

```
 <div class="search-container">
      <input type="text" list="containerlist" />
        <datalist id="list">
          <option> id="containerlist" value="?"</option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
```

The output should be, I can click into the search bar, and start to type and the dropdown list will appear and filter as I continue to refine my search.

Comment: Please add your JavaScript code.

Comment: you can see how to use datalist with input here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp. You would then need to add all the <option>'s dynamically based on the data you pull from your db

Comment: @JackBashford 
function getcontainers() {
    // window.alert ("get containers");
    var select = document.getElementById("containerlist");
    var table = document.getElementById("maintable"); 

    var prior_container = "";
    for(var i = 1; i<table.rows.length; i++)
    {
 if(table.rows[i].cells[01].innerHTML!==prior_container)
     {
         var option = document.createElement('option');
         option.text = option.value = table.rows[i].cells[01].innerHTML;
         select.add(option, 0);
  prior_container = table.rows[i].cells[01].innerHTML;
     };
    };
};

Comment: @Kenci I have 100+ options in my datalist and this list is continuously being added too (nothing is every deleted). Are you saying I would have to add each option dynamically, and every time new data is added to my dataset?